# draw function with paper.js on multiple function

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am implementing a draw app. I am trying to use paper.js to simplify lines and make them smooth.
I am trying to use method from [paper.js how to set up multiple canvases using only javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865863/paper-js-how-to-set-up-multiple-canvases-using-only-javascript). However, it seems not working for me.
When I move to each canvas, I want to setup new "paper" so that I can draw stuff on that canvas.

Here are part of my codes:

```
    var page = PDFViewerApplication.page;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('annotation'+page);
    if(canvas != null && canvas != undefined) {
      if (pCanvas.indexOf(page) <= -1) { //make sure for each canvas only setup "paper" once
        var mypaper = new paper.PaperScope();
        mypaper.setup(canvas);
        //paper.setup(canvas);
        pCanvas.push(page);
        if(mypapers[page] == undefined || mypapers[page] == null) {
          mypapers[page] = mypaper;
        }

      }
    }
    //if(mypapers[page])
    path = new mypapers[page].Path();
    path.strokeColor = gcolor;
    path.strokeWidth = gline;
    path.strokeCap = 'round';
    path.strokeJoin = 'round';
    path.add(new paper.Point(window.lastMousex.x, window.lastMousex.y));
```

When mouseup I will use path.Simplify to smooth the line. Sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot and finally found...

```
  path.simplify();
  //path.smooth();
  mypapers[cpage].view.draw();
```

Use this when mouseup. Everything works fine now.